# How config .htaccess to subpages apear like second domain?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have two domains (ex: **domain1 .com** and **domain2 .com**), and the wordpress installed in first domain, **domain1 .com**.

I want the page **domain1 .com/pageABC/** and subpages, appear and access with **domain2 .com**

I try config the .htaccess to hide or substitute (if is the correct description) the **domain1 .com/pageABC/** and all subpages (ex: **domain1 .com/pageABC/subpage/**), and just see the second domain: **domain2 .com** and **domain2 .com/subpage/** etc.

How i can do this? I already try the multisite option, but is not functional to my school project.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the answer right away, here :

```
RedirectMatch "^/pageABC/(.*)" "http://domain2.com/pageABC/$1"
```

---

**The Breakdown**

**RedirectMatch** is a command that allows you to redirect a URL by a **regular expression (Regex)**.

The next part, "^/pageABC/(.*)", is the URL that induces the redirect. The **^** symbol simply finds everything behind it (As in the domain name), and the **(.*)** regex matches **every subpage of pageABC**.

**"http://domain2.com/pageABC/$1"** is the redirect URL. The **$1** operator simply gets the content of the (.*) regex, causing all subpages to be saved and included in the redirect.

---

**Not working for you?**
If this command does not work, keep in mind that older attempts in htaccess modification may be saved, and you may need to clear **browser cache** to fix this. **(It will work perfectly in an incognito window)**

Comment: Thanks. I put that code line in .htaccess of 2# domain. the RedirectMatch works, but in address bar appear the 1# domain instead of 2# domain. that is possible? thanks

Comment: The htaccess file worked for me. I quickly repurposed a useless directory on my website to perform a similar task to the one you want, using the code above. https://simpodex.com/extras

Comment: tell me the directory you want me to redirect to domain 2 and the domain you want it to redirect to

Comment: The 1# domain have wordpress (in public_html), the 2# domain just addon. I already try config the 2# like alias. I try put a "mask" in **domain1.com/store** to **appear mydomainstore.com**, and  **domain1.com/store/product** appear **mydomainstore.com/product**, etc

Comment: OH, ok. Now I understand. So you want to make it look like a separate domain. Unfortunately, this is not a very good idea, because anyone who will reference that URL will end up with a broken link. In fact, I have never seen such a feat ever done with htaccess. I think it is not possible without purchasing 2 individual domains, as htaccess automatically redirects the user to the url if you rewrite the URL bar.